# How to load dependencies from a local directory in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

In a Maven project, I know I can download and copy dependencies specified in pom.xml to a local directory using this command:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=./lib
```

How do I tell maven to use this newly created directory containing all the jars when doing maven install instead of the central Maven repository?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you want to save bandwidth, or do you have security reasons, or something else?

Comment: If you have used copy-dependencies all the artifacts are already in your `$HOME/.m2/repository` so I simply don't understand your question?

Comment: I want to check in the dependencies as a part my personal repository in git, so that it can be run on multiple machines in an internal network.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache the artifacts on an internal network, I'd suggest setting up a repository mirror.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html